# How to overcome the git bash error occur when enable the two factor authentication in GitHub

Tags: authentication, github, two-factor-authentication

Very recently I have activated the two-factor authentication on GitHub. Then after I tried to push my work (using git bash)to a new repository and it `displays a error as the username or password is incorrect.` How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you're still using your username and password stored in a credential manager for pushing to GitHub, and that won't work when you're using two-factor authentication.  The [Git FAQ explains how to empty your credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials) (replace `your-username`):

```
$ echo url=https://your-username@github.com | git credential reject
```

Then, the next time you push, Git will prompt your for your credentials.  Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and create a personal access token with the `repo` and `workflow` scopes, and then give Git your username when it asks and the personal access token for your password.  Don't specify your actual password, since that won't work.

On Windows, you may see a graphical prompt to sign into GitHub; you can just close that window and follow the steps above.